# Don't show GUI when run ilixi app on ubuntu 14.04 lts

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, x11, directfb

I'm learning ilixi toolkit. I compiled and install successed source code from [guide page](http://www.ilixi.org/documentation/installation/)

When run app sample, app run but don't show gui. What did I missed step or need add new some configure?

[image]

I use ubuntu 14.04LTS 32 bit, on a virtual machine VMWare.

Configure in file .directfbrc is:

> pixelformat=ARGB
>
> system=x11
>
> force-windowed

Thanks for help !

Answer (score 0):

DirectFB version 1.7 with multi application core support requires linuxfusion and linuxone drivers either you need to install/compile from source and load those two kernel modules. Currently the DirectFB site is down (Not sure what is the current state of the project). There is git repository of source available if you wish to do the compilation yourself

[Link to github repo](https://github.com/deniskropp/linux-fusion)

Comment: Thanks for answer, BalaC. I using DirectFB 1.7 to run application. In my question, I compile, run with single app no success. I compiled with multi application [link] (http://www.ilixi.org/documentation/installation-multi-app/) is OK. Like for your answer "linuxfusion and linuxone"

Comment: I never tried ilixi with single app instance so can't comment on the behavior. Does my answer solve your problem (or) you still have issue with it.